# Selective averaging in python

Tags: python, random

so this code just randomises the list 1,2,3,4(x4) then writes it out into text file and reads it back out. It prints all the 16, however i was wondering if there was a way make 4 groups of 4 out of the 16, then I could define it and call them individually and take an average of only 4 of them.

```
import random
members = 5
participants=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
random.shuffle(participants)
with open("myfile1.txt",'w') as tf:
    for i in range(len(participants) // members + 1):
        group = participants[i*members:i*members + members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant))
            tf.write("\n")

with open("myfile1.txt",'r') as tf:
    for line in tf.readlines():
        print(line)

def ing():
    with open('myfile1.txt','r') as file:
        print(sum(list(map(int,[elem for elem in file.read().split('\n') if elem!='']))))
```

Sorry its a bit waffly, basically want to take an average of the first 4 numbers it spits out!

Thanks!

new code:

```
import numpy
import random
members, n_groups = 4, 4
participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
print participants 
random.shuffle(participants)

with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
    for i in range(n_groups):
        group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
            tf.write('\n')

with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
    g = [map(int, line.split()) for line in tf.readlines()]
    print g 
    print numpy.mean(g, axis=1)
```

Still doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: Not sure what you want here. What is the criteria for grouping?

Comment: the code that writes something to the file and\or reads it is irrelevant here. Please try to focus on the problem and post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: no criteria for grouping just in put into 4 groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing one number per line, you could directly write a group of numbers. For that you just need to remove `write('\n')` from the 2nd for and add a space.
You can then upload directly each group of 4 *members* using `line.split()` (I added a transformation to retrieve the int format but you can change it to float or whatever you need).
Using numpy, you can compute the mean for each group.

Which gives:

```
import numpy
import random
members, n_groups = 4, 4
participants= range(1,members+1)*n_groups
print participants
random.shuffle(participants)

with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
    for i in range(n_groups):
        group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
        tf.write('\n')

with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
    g = [map(int, line.split()) for line in tf.readlines()]
    print g
    print numpy.mean(g, axis=1)
```

Output

```
# participants
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# g
[[3, 3, 2, 2], [4, 1, 1, 4], [2, 2, 4, 3], [3, 1, 4, 1]]
# mean per group
[ 2.5   2.5   2.75  2.25]
```

New *myfile1.txt*

```
3 3 2 2 
4 1 1 4 
2 2 4 3 
3 1 4 1
```

Comment: Just tried it, i had to put brackets around participants and g near print then said "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'range' and 'int'" not sure why its not working?

Comment: It's because I used Python2 and you Python3. You can replace by `participants= list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups`, it should solved your problem :)

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason? Ill put the new code in an edited version